# Looping solutions to While statements?

Tags: java, random, while-loop, numbers

I have a while statement that produces a a number between 15 and 32, and 212 and 229.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class Test
{
public static void main(String[] args)

{
    int randNum = 0;
    Random randNumList = new Random();

    while( !(randNum>=15 && randNum<=32)&& !(randNum>=212 && randNum<=229))
     {
        randNum = randNumList.nextInt(251);
     }
     System.out.println(randNum);
```

What type of loop can I use to produce a given number (such as 10) of these "randNum"'s produced? For example, if the while statement produced the number 24, how could I produce 10 more numbers between 15/32 and 212/229 from that while statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while your way of creating a random may not be the most efficient -- the least invasive change to your code would be to simply wrap your while in a for loop ... you can add the results to an Array, or a List to access them later.

```
Random randNumList = new Random(); //do this only once - no need to re-create it you can re-use it

for(int i=0; i<asManyAsYouWantPlusOne; i++){

       randNum = 0; //important! reset here or you will end up with all the same random numbers ...

       while( !(randNum>=15 && randNum<=32)&& !(randNum>=212 && randNum<=229))
       {
         randNum = randNumList.nextInt(251);
       }
      //add to list, or array here ...
       System.out.println(randNum);
     }
```

Comment: You definitely shouldn't be creating a `new Random()` in each iteration of the outer loop!

Comment: I added this code into the program, but again, only one number came up. My question is a bit unclear, I apologize. What I am trying to get is a list of 10 different numbers, all of which are between 15/32 and 212/229. Thank you for your input though!

Comment: Thank you so much! I would upvote but I don't have enough reputation!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly what you are proposing, you can simply add a for loop around it, as in:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    while( !(randNum>=15 && randNum<=32)&& !(randNum>=212 && randNum<=229))
    {
        randNum = randNumList.nextInt(251);
    }
    System.out.println(randNum);
}
```

However, you while loop is ineffective, because it generates several numbers needlessly. You could simply ask for a number from a smaller range (between 15 and 32 there are (32-15+1=) 18 numbers, and between 212 and 229 there are other (229-212+1=) 18 numbers - 36 total numbers, so), and adjust it, as in:

```
randNum = randNumList.nextInt(36)+15; // this creates numbers between 15 and 50
if(randNum > 32) randNum += 179; // this transforms the numbers between 33 and 50
                                 // in numbers between 212 and 229
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments in response to Birgit Martinelle, it appears your actual goal is to guarantee a set of **unique** values from the specified ranges. (If so, you should say so in your question rather than in comments, because that's a totally different problem.)

A decent solution is to shuffle the set and iterate through the result to pick out a subset:

```
ArrayList<Integer> al = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for(int i = 15; i < 33; ++i) {
   al.add(i);
}
for(int i = 212; i < 230; ++i) {
   al.add(i);
}

// Repeat (loop over) the following lines as many times as you need subsets.
Collections.shuffle(al);
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
   System.out.println(al.get(i));
}
```

Your current rejection scheme is terribly inefficient -- you throw away 216/251 (more than 85%) of your attempts.